# ¿Cómo genero un LOGIN automatico?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Quiero que la procedure me cree un usuario a partir del dni y una contraseña (con la primera letra del nombre y el tipo(que es tipo integer asi que 0,1,2).
Me da un error de SQL statement ignored y "TIPO" identificador no válido.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Proyecto1718 IS
              PROCEDURE generarLogin (v_dni IN VARCHAR , v_nombre IN VARCHAR, v_tipo IN VARCHAR) AS
                usuario VARCHAR(15);
                pass VARCHAR(15);
              BEGIN 
                usuario := LOWER(v_dni);
                pass := LOWER(substr(v_nombre, 1, 1) || v_tipo);
                 INSERT INTO login (usuario, contraseña, tipo) VALUES (usuario, pass, v_tipo);
              EXCEPTION 
                WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20100, 'ERROR INESPERADO AL GENERAR EL LOGIN - USUARIO/CONTRASEÑA: '|| SQLERRM);
              END generarLogin;
            END Proyecto1718;

//TABLA DE LOGIN
CREATE TABLE Login (
  id_login INTEGER 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                      MINVALUE 1
                      MAXVALUE 999999
                      INCREMENT BY 1
                      START WITH 1
                      NOORDER NOCYCLE NOT NULL
                      ENABLE
           CONSTRAINT id_lo_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  usuario VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  contraseña VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  id_persona INTEGER NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT id_per_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_persona) REFERENCES Persona (id_persona));
```

Comment: No sé qué me falla o por qué no me crea el paquete y tampoco sé si esto me generaría un usuario y una contraseña...

Comment: El error te da al intentar compilar, supongo. No entiendo muy bien, si dices que el tipo es numérico, ¿por qué la variable v_tipo es VARCHAR?

Comment: En eso no me había fijado, gracias. Pero de todas formas me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el error exacto que te da oracle? Incluso el número de línea donde se produce.

Comment: "-Error(8, 6): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" y "-Error(8,47): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TIPO": identificador no válido" y me lo compila, pero con errores.

Comment: Fijate que en 

    PROCEDURE generarLogin (v_dni IN VARCHAR , v_nombre IN VARCHAR, v_tipo IN VARCHAR) AS
                usuario VARCHAR(15);
                pass VARCHAR(15);

No estás declarando la variable 'tipo' ,

Comment: No se si se me escapa algo pero 'tipo' es un campo de la base de datos, no una variable. Aún así, no consigo ver nada. Necesitaria que añadieras también la estructura de la tabla 'login'.

Comment: Ya está añadida la tabla de login

Answer (score 0):

Te comento lo que he visto:

1. No veo que exista en la tabla el campo 'tipo'. Es obvio que si el campo no existe no lo puedas guardar. Crea el campo primero o quítalo del insert si no lo quieres guardar.
2. ¿Tienes triggers que afecten a esta tabla?

   2.1. *Si, tengo triggers:* ¿El trigger rellena el campo id_persona? Si no es el caso, debes añadir a tu insert dicho campo, ya que lo tienes declarado como **NOT NULL**.

   2.2. *No, no tengo triggers:* Tienes dos opciones; crear un trigger para que lo rellene o, como he indicado en el apartado 2.1, añadir al insert el campo id_persona.
3. Esto no es un error, es un consejo. Dentro de la medida de lo posible, intenta siempre declarar los campos del tipo de la tabla. Por ejemplo, el parámetro de entrada *v_dni* lo declaras como tipo **VARCHAR**. Si en lugar de eso lo declaras de tipo *login.usuario* también se declarará como un **VARCHAR**, pero si cambias el tipo de campo a VARCHAR(50), no tendrás que modificar tu procedimiento porque ya toma directamente el tipo del campo de la tabla. Sería de la siguiente manera:

> PROCEDURE generarLogin (v_dni IN login.usuario%TYPE, ...

Y lo mismo con la variable *usuario*

> usuarion login.usuario%TYPE;

En principio con estos cambios debería funcionar. Pruébalo y comenta a ver que tal.